# Jsoup: different Document structure while loading HTML from URL and from file

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to parse data from website.
I need to parse data both from a URL and from a local HTML file, but the contents of the Document **for the same web page**, obtained from the link and from its HTML file, which I manually downloaded, are different.

When I use:

```java
Document pageDocument = Jsoup.connect(pageUrl)
```

My target fragment of `pageDocument` looks like this:

```html
<div class="rcol" style="width:700px; padding:0 0 0 6px;">
   //some target data
</div>
```

But when i use:

```java
Document pageDocument = Jsoup.parse(htmlFile, "UTF-8", baseUrl)
```

Its looks like this:

```html
<a class="attribute-value">rcol</a>" <span class="attribute-name">style</span>="<a class="attribute-value">width:700px; padding:0 0 0 6px;</a>
```

So hundreds of lines of logic that I wrote to parse this document, obtained by URL, not working to the same file, obtained manually.
**IMPORTANT**: the content of the manually downloaded HTML file is completely identical to the file from the URL, I was check it. Differences appear only after I pass file to Jsoup.parse()!
**QUESTION**: why does the content of the HTML file changes after passing to Jsoup.parse() and how to prevent it?

**UPD**: I noticed that the length of the source code of the page in the browser and the length of the downloaded HTML file differ by one line. Looks like a closing tag was missing during the download or something else. I tried to manually create an HTML file by doing ctrl-c, ctrl-v of the page source code in browser and my assumption was confirmed - the file created in this way is parsed correctly.
I still don't know why this is happening and would like to know. But if you are reading this post in the future, and the answer has not been found - keep in mind and ***recheck the HTML structure again***